# How to go about solving this definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I go about solving the following integral:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin x)^{\cos x} (\cos x \cot x - \log (\sin x)^{\sin x})\, dx$$

Giving a first try doesn't help as the starting point cannot be grasped that is to say it baffles that how and where to start. The hint given is substitute $u =(\sin x)^{\cos x}$ then what remains to be computed is $\frac {d}{dx}  (\sin x)^{\cos x}$ that is a problem in itself as it is differentiating exponential function of a function. Any thoughts:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:Take $u={\sin x}^{\cos x}$ and find $du$

Comment: @ResearchEngineer yes

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$d\left( (\sin  x)^{ \cos  x } \right) =(\sin  x)^{ \cos  x }(\cos  x\cot  x-\log  (\sin  x)^{ \sin  x })dx$$ (you can check it) so from Newton- Leibniz formula  we can conclude that $$\\ \\ \\ \int _{ 0 }^{ \pi /2 } \left( \sin  x \right) ^{ \cos  x }\left( \cos  x\cot  x-\log  \left( \sin  x \right) ^{ \sin  x } \right) dx=\left( \sin { \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }  \right) ^{ \cos { \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }  }-{ \left( \sin { 0 }  \right)  }^{ \cos { 0 }  }=1-0=1\\ $$

Comment: There's an extra $dx$ in there.  Either $df(x) = f'(x) \, dx$ or $\dfrac d{dx} f(x) = f'(x)$, but not $\dfrac d{dx} f(x) = f'(x) \, dx$.

Comment: @tilper, thank you for correction